# Android Eclipse placing a text view in specific places

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, textview

I'm creating this in a XML file and want a text view to be placed in a specific spot.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" 
/>
```

It's underneath the last button that was placed so it's around in the middle of the screen.  I want it to be at the bottom of the screen of to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Easy if you're using a RelativeLayout as parent.

```
android:layout_alignParentRight
android:layout_alignParentBottom
```

(check the capitalization, I'm not anywhere I can double check).

Comment: Ok, but what if I want it lets say, some where in the middle in a certain spot.  Is there a pixel alignment.  I tried android:layout_margrin="25dp"  or something like that already.  Maybe I did it wrong or theres another way?

Comment: The best you'll get is to use RelativeLayout and then adjust margins to move it around from there.  You could do `android:layout_centerInParent` to place it the exact center then use margins to shift it from there, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.  If anyone else reads this is what I did was use android:layoutmarginRight (or something similair to that) ="25dp" (which is the size).  And just played with the numbers for the right, left, top, & bottom untill it looked right.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ***RelativeLayout*** would be perfect if you would be specifying each views' positions. It is the most flexible layout among the Android Layouts.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/). It discussed how to position views in a RelativeLayout.

I hope you can get ideas from it in solving your problem.